# Software for quickly tagging photo catalogue and export to spreadsheet?

Tags: software-rec, photos, spreadsheet, tags

We have 3000 photos that we want to quickly flip through and tag into different categories, and export that information into a spreadsheet. The software can be very simple (I am not doing any editing, post processing, etc.)

I know software like iPhoto can do tagging, but I want to produce a final spreadsheet that has one column with the photo filenames, and columns to the right of it representing each tag. If a particular photo (row) is tagged in a category, it will be indicated in the corresponding cell.

FLOSS preferred but not absolutely necessary.

Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Any decent photo manager should allow you to tag. It is the information export that may cause problems. What sort of information do you want included in the spreadsheet report?

Comment: @music2myear I edited my question to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @wizlog Windows XP and Mac OS X. I hope the software will at least work in Windows, but preferably in Mac OS X, too.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [Picasa](http://picasa.google.nl) to flip through the photo's and tag them.
- Use [exiftool](https://sites.google.com/site/picasastartersite/other-tools/exiftool) to extract the information.
- You can even [create buttons](https://sites.google.com/site/picasastartersite/custom-picasa-buttons/exportcsv) inside Picasa to execute a batch script using exiftool.

Answer (score 0):

[FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) is great for what you're describing, but it's expensive. [Bento](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/mac.html), the life-oriented version, is a bit cheaper, but not much.

Comment: Sounds a little too heavy duty for my needs. But would I be able to flip through the photos very quickly and tag them quickly with Bento?

Comment: @penyuan That's what it advertises. I'm pretty sure they have a trial, so you don't have to drop the money now.

Comment: What did I do to deserve a downvote? :'-(

Answer (score 0):

Look... Putting file names and  tags into an Excel Spreadsheet is very doable and easy with C#.
You could use software like [Picasa](http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=CNUnfv0pVToyhLoGm0AHH2fHRA9bSoNUB2vrKrAvc6vA4CAAQASDHmPgFUPf0mKb______wFgyf6ai8Ck2A-gAcTSy_4DyAEBqgQST9BKC2ggChzrUFjBu-sYqlfBgAWQTg&sig=AOD64_1nhprcevew_-J6L9_20BJHQcQogA&ved=0CAwQ0Qw&adurl=http://picasa.google.com/%23utm_campaign%3Den%26utm_source%3Den-ha-na-us-bk%26utm_medium%3Dha%26utm_term%3Dpicasa)... or you could just:

If you can use a computer with Windows 7 or Windows Vista, then you can easily sort by tags, just as you would by date.

In Windows Vista and 7... To add a tag, I simply opened my **Pictures** folder, clicked a photo of my mom, and then clicked the area next to **Tags** in the Details pane at the bottom of the folder window. (If the Details pane isn’t visible, click **Organize**, click **Layout**, and then click **Details Pane**.) In this case, I'll type the tag “mom” into the **Tags** (you can add more than one tag, and separate them using a semicolon in the Tags box) box, and then press ENTER.

[image: To then sort by tag...]

Comment: However, Windows stores this information with the file and is generally not very good at exporting the information.

Comment: @digitxp please A) give a specific example; B) if all you want to do is sort, then put each tag group into its own folder

Comment: A) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_explorer#cite_ref-12 B) The OP wants to be able to consolidate this information into a table.

Comment: This is nice, but I don't see how I can tabulate the information into a spreadsheet...

Comment: Why would you want to?